# What is the difference between a VLAN and a subnet?

Tags: subnet, vlan

I have read numerous forums and articles regarding VLANs and subnets.
However, I haven't understood the functions of each apart from the following:

1. Subnets allow the segmentation of a network
2. VLANs are an isolated portion of a network

**Questions**

1. If I have multiple subnets I assume that you would need a router to communicate between each subnet. Only devices within each subnet would be in the local broadcast domain for that subnet. Is that right?
2. Do I need a subnet to setup a VLAN?
3. I am aware that a VLAN can exist within a subnet. But my understanding is that you would have to assign an IP address of that subnet to the VLAN. How can it be isolated from the rest of the subnet?
4. When would you set up a VLAN? Especially if I am able to segment my network using subnets?
5. I keep coming across the following point. However, I am unsure what this exactly means when it reads `same physical network`.

   > Virtual local area networks (VLANs) allow us to create different logical and physical networks; whereas IP subnetting simply allows us to create logical networks through the same physical network.

Would appreciate real-world examples.

Comment: The major difference is that joining a subnet is based on client side IP configuration. Therefore the client can use any subnet he wants. For a VLAN the configuration is done on server side (e.g. based on LAN port) and the client can not change it. From a security perspective this is a big difference.

Comment: @Robert - Can you elaborate on what you mean by `client side IP and server side configuration`?

Comment: A subnet is determined by the IP you use and the IP can be chosen by the admin of a computer (or device). Therefore it is done on client side - you can not control it. A VLAN is configured at server/router side. The one who controls the router/server decides which computer/port is assigned to which VLAN. One (or some) central routers/servers can be protected logically (login password) and physically (access to server room).

Comment: This page may be useful http://www.petri.co.il/csc_setup_a_vlan_on_a_cisco_switch.htm

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Reading through your comments, it sounds like you're seeing some confusion about the various network layers in the OSI model.  VLANs operate on Layer 2 while IP Subnets operate on Layer 3.

Comment: @Robert IP can be chosen by network admin by configuring appropriate entry in DHCP.. isn't it so?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Subnet - is a range of IP addresses determined by part of an address (often called the network address) and a subnet mask (netmask).  For example, if the netmask is `255.255.255.0` (or /24 for short), and the network address is `192.168.10.0`, then that defines a range of IP addresses `192.168.10.0` through `192.168.10.255`.  Shorthand for writing that is `192.168.10.0/24`.

VLAN - A good way to think of this is "switch partitioning."  Let's say you have an 8 port switch that is VLAN-able.  You can assign 4 ports to one VLAN (say VLAN 1) and 4 ports to another VLAN (say VLAN 2).  VLAN 1 won't see any of VLAN 2's traffic and vice versa, logically, you now have two separate switches.  Normally on a switch, if the switch hasn't seen a MAC address it will "flood" the traffic to all other ports.  VLANs prevent this.

If two computers are going to talk using TCP/IP, then one of two conditions must be met:

- They must belong to the same subnet.  This means the network address must be the same and the netmask must be equal or smaller.  So, a computer with an interface with an IP address of `192.168.10.4/24` can talk to a computer with an interface with an IP address of `192.168.10.8/24` with no issues, provided they are both connected to the same physical switch or VLAN.  If the second computer's interface connected to that same physical switch or VLAN was `192.168.11.8/24`, it would ignore the traffic (unless the interface was in promiscuous mode).
- A router needs to exist between both computers that can forward traffic between subnets.  Computer A and computer B need a route (or default gateway) to this router.  Let's say a computer with an interface with an IP address of `192.168.10.4/24` wants to talk to a computer with an interface with an IP address of `192.168.20.4/24`.  Different subnets, so we must go through a router.  Let's say there's a router with two interfaces (routers by definition have two interfaces), one on `192.168.10.254/24` and `192.168.20.254/24`.  If the route table or DHCP is setup correctly and both computer A and B can reach the router's interfaces on their respective subnets, then they can talk to each other indirectly via the router.

Forcing traffic to go through a router, even though it's not needed such as on our 8-port switch above, has security and performance benefits - it gives you an opportunity to filter traffic, an opportunity to optimally route traffic based on type, and routers do not forward broadcast traffic (unless unusually configured).  VLANs are sometimes used as a "hack" to manage flows/visibility of IPv4 broadcast traffic.

Edit to answer some of your questions:

- Conceptually VLANs are equivalent to switches.  What comes in 1 port of a VLAN is replicated("flooded") to all other ports unless the VLAN has seen/learned the MAC address before, then it is directed to that port.  There is no gateway to the VLAN proper.  A "gateway" always means the IP address of a router.
- For VLAN 1 to talk to VLAN 2, an interface in VLAN 1 must be connected to a router, an interface in VLAN 2 must be connected to a router, and that router must be configured to forward traffic between those subnets.  In our 8 port example above, if we wanted to route traffic between those VLANs, we'd have to spend 1 port on each VLAN connecting to a router.  Same with a switch.

I'm sure many high-end switches/hardware have a "VLAN router" "built-in" to them where spending an extra port within each VLAN connecting it to a physical router really isn't necessary if you want to route between VLANs in the same switch.  This might be where the VLAN IP or "gateway" comes into play.  (I invite those more knowledgeable to edit this)

Update: On Cisco switches, there's a feature called SVI or "Switched Virtual Interfaces" which basically act as the router between VLANs.

- When a computer gets its IP via DHCP, it also usually gets the "default gateway" from that same DHCP server.  Someone has to configure the DHCP server correctly.  Routing protocols such as RIP, IS-IS, OSPF, and BGP can also add routes.  Of course you have the option of adding routes manually ("static" routes)
- If your switch has a serial port or port labeled "console" it's likely managed and supports VLANs.

Comment: One of the best explanations I have seen today. Now that has raised a number of questions. Would VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 have its own IP address or is it simply tagged as VLAN 1 and VLAN 2? If they are tagged, how do the hosts/end points/nodes in VLAN 1 talk to each other? Now if there is a router, is the gateway the VLAN IP address or that of the router? When you say `route table`, is it something I have to build? Also how do you know if a switch you have inherited is VLAN-able (managed) or unmanaged?

Comment: Please see edits.

Comment: Thanks. I had a question regarding the sentence `ven though it's not needed such as on our 8-port switch above, has security and performance benefits`. Why would it not have to go through a router if the the subnets are part of a different network?

Comment: Please see more edits.

Comment: Simply the best answer to this sort of VLAN vs Subnetting.

Answer (score 20):

I found the other explanations complicated.

- VLAN lets you tag all network packets with a magic number (e.g. **`3`**).
- Only other network cards set to **`3`** will see those packets

Set a bunch of computers to **`VLAN 3`** and they'll be in their own little isolated world; they won't see any other traffic.

Suddenly you can have multiple *LANs* operating on the same wires (i.e. *virtual LANs*). You can even have two computers with the same IP, since they have a different VLAN tags (e.g. `3` verses`7`)

---

Setting a VLAN ID is done by configuring the network card driver:

[image]

Your mileage will vary with your network card and its drivers.

Comment: I have come across VLAN tags however am intrigued by how do you `set` network cards to say `3`? I assume that the VLANs would not be able to see each other if there is no router. If there is a router I am guessing there would have to be a firewall to prevent the packets from being passed from one VLAN to the next if a requets is made. Now what would be the gateway of the subnet in the VLAN? Would it be the router?

Comment: Also is the VLAN allocated an IP address or simply a tag? Based on my readings at petri.co.il/csc_setup_a_vlan_on_a_cisco_switch.htm it seems trunks can also `route` packets. Not sure if my understanding is clear though. Does that mean a switch is a layer 2 and 3 device?

Comment: A VLAN is simply a tag. All network cards must be aware of the presence of a VLAN tag, and ignore packets with a different VLAN tag than their own.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Must all NICs be VLAN aware?  I thought that the edge switches between the VLANs could handle all the tagging (and removing of tags) from the Ehternet header.

Comment: In the case of a smart switch like that: no, the switch can handle directing traffic. But in that case you have to program the switch to know what ports takes what traffic. From the simpler explanation of what VLAN is: it's a way of tagging packets with an ID, so that only network cards with the same tag see them.

Answer (score 8):

The simplistic explanation is that VLANs exist to allow different subnets to share physical cabling, ports, and switching.  You could have distinct subnets on your network without vlans, but you'd have to have a different set of wires for each.

Comment: I have finally understood that from trawling the web that a VLAN allows an organization to utilize the same switch as opposed to purchasing multiple switches however am still confused about some of the questions I raised in my post.

Comment: What?  There's nothing preventing one from operating multiple IP subnets on the same physical network, though I can't think of any good reasons to do it without VLANs in place.  In particular, you'd have some serious difficulty with DHCP without VLANs to isolate broadcast traffic.

Answer (score 4):

> 1.If I have multiple subnets I assume that you would need a router to communicate between each subnet.

Yes, you need a router to move packets between subnets.

> Only devices within each subnet would be in the local broadcast domain for that subnet. Is that right?

Yes, a subnet is a broadcast domain.

> 2.Do I need a subnet to setup a VLAN?

Yes.

> 3.I am aware that a VLAN can exist within a subnet but my understanding is that you would have to assign the VLAN an IP address of that subnet.

No, as I understand it, VLANs are defined in the switches and isolate the traffic of each VLAN.

> How can it be isolated from the rest of the subnet?

A VLAN *is* a subnet.

> 4.When would you set up a VLAN especially if I am able to segment my network using subnets?

When you need to segregate traffic into two or more groups without separating the physical infrastructure (chiefly switches) into two or more physical groups.

> 5.I keep coming across the point that Virtual local area networks (VLANs) allow us to create different logical and physical networks; whereas IP subnetting simply allows us to create logical networks through the same physical network. however am unsure what this exactly means when it reads same physical network.

A physical LAN is comprised mostly of switches and cables arranged (in the case of Ethernet) into a single tree structure.

Normally a LAN is a single subnet. An organisation might have several LANs linked by routers.

A single physical LAN can be split into several logical LANs (VLANs) using VLAN support in the switches. Each VLAN then has a separate subnet. A router is therefore needed to move packets between the logical LANs (VLANs).

---

Update: some answers to follow up questions in comments.

> if I wanted devices on 2 separate VLANs to communicate that a router is not needed as I can use trunking.

Here's some quotes from http://www.formortals.com/an-introduction-to-vlan-trunking/

"*VLAN trunking allows a single network adapter to behave as “n” number of virtual network adapters, where ”n” has a theoretical upper limit of 4096 but is typically limited to 1000 VLAN network segments.*"

"*Routers can become infinitely more useful once they are trunked in to the enterprise switch infrastructure.  Once trunked, they become omnipresent and can provide routing services to any subnet in any corner of the enterprise network.*"

So you still need a router but, with VLAN trunking, it can be a one-armed router (router on a stick). High end switches include routing capabilities, so you may not need a separate router because your high-end switch is also a layer 3 router.

> When you say that I need a subnet to setup a VLAN what do you mean exactly?

VLANs are a layer 2 concept. Just as Ethernet switches are a layer 2 device. VLANs can make a couple of switches do jobs where you might otherwise need half a dozen switches in isolated groups. However your nodes (computers, printers, etc) typically use layer-3 addressing (IP).

For nodes in one VLAN (N for Network) to communicate with nodes in another VLAN (N for Network) you need an InterNetwork Protocol (in other words IP). In IP to move packets between Networks we need each Network to have a different layer-3 network address.

This is where sub-netting comes in - dividing an organisation's allocated layer-3 network address range into sub-networks by using subnet masks. Then you can use a router to allow devices in one subnet (in one VLAN) to communicate with devices in another subnet (in another VLAN).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - Thanks. When you say that I need a subnet to setup a VLAN what do you mean exactly? To me subnetting is the segregation or segmentation of IP addresses? From what I have understood VLANs operate in Layer 2 which means it resolves MAC addresses to IP address so assuming my understanding is correct,  why and how would you create a subnet to setup a VLAN? I did not follow what you meant by `VLAN is defined in the switches and isolates the traffic of each VLAN`?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - It also seems that if I wanted devices on 2 separate VLANs to communicate that a router is not needed as I can use trunking.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey It's possible perhaps that you both might be incorrectly interchanging the terms VLAN and VLANs. Him as a mistype in one sentence you read of his, and you in your mind. VLANs is the plural of VLAN. So this sentence he wrote "VLAN is defined in the switches and isolates the traffic of each VLAN?"  should perhaps read "VLANs are defined in the/each switch, and traffic on each VLAN is isolated"

Comment: @barlop - I do understand that a VLAN is a subset of VLANs however am getting confused by the content in the link you suggested i.e.http://www.petri.co.il/csc_setup_a_vlan_on_a_cisco_switch.htm. For example the content reads `At this point, only ports 2 and 3 should be able to communicate with each other and ports 4 & 5 should be able to communicate. That is because each of these is in its own VLAN`

Comment: `For the device on port 2 to communicate with the device on port 4, you would have to configure a trunk port to a router so that it can strip off the VLAN information, route the packet, and add back the VLAN information`

Comment: But later down the page it reads `For devices in different VLAN’s to communicate, you must use a router or Layer 3 switch.` unless I have misunderstood the context of the content.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Looks likely that what I said earier was wrong then.. And a switch with VLANs DOES Route i.e. when multiple VLANs i.e. it's not just a layer 2 device. If it was there'd be no communication between the VLANs. So RedGrittyBrick was right in what he said in point 1. Another point I wasn't accurate on, is a VLAN can be made across switches. or I suppose within a switch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1722/discussion-between-barlop-and-peanutsmonkey)

Comment: anybody else is welcome to add any thoughts to the chat

Comment: @barlop - Not true. You can absolutely route between VLANs on a switch -- it's entirely up to how you configure it (at least with Cisco). We have some isolated VLANs (no routing), and others that do.

Comment: @Uninspired    If you read the comment I made 4 hours ago, I said "Looks likely that what I said earier was wrong then.. And a switch with VLANs DOES Route i.e. when multiple VLANs i.e. it's not just a layer 2 device."

Comment: i'm going to delete that first comment I made about it not routing.. 'cos people may not read the follow up one that corrected it.

Comment: It might be best for me to delete this answer. The number of comments suggests it isn't really helping.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1.If I have multiple subnets I assume that you would need a router to communicate between each subnet. Only devices within each subnet would be in the local broadcast domain for that subnet. Is that right?

IP Networks (subnets) are a layer 3 concept.  If two PC's are attached to the same L2 switch without VLAN's they will be in the same L2 broadcast domain, but not L3 broadcast domain.

2.Do I need a subnet to setup a VLAN?

No.  However, if you want devices in a VLAN to communicate with one another they will likely need some L3 protocol.

3.I am aware that a VLAN can exist within a subnet but my understanding is that you would have to assign the VLAN an IP address of that subnet. How can it be isolated from the rest of the subnet?

Not clear what you are asking.

4.When would you set up a VLAN especially if I am able to segment my network using subnets?

VLANs are simply a way of making a L2 device appear to be multiple L2 devices.

5.I keep coming across the point that Virtual local area networks (VLANs) allow us to create different logical and physical networks; whereas IP subnetting simply allows us to create logical networks through the same physical network. however am unsure what this exactly means when it reads same physical network.

Comment: When you say that they will be in the same Layer 2 broadcast domain and not the Layer 3 broadcats domain, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: It means that if a packet, with all ones in the MAC destination field, is transmitted it will be seen by all devices.  The layer 3 broadcast domain can be all ones in the IP address or network numbers are equal and the host portion of the address is all ones.  Before you move on to VLANs you need to understand the basics of Layer 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank. Could you further elaborate on what you mean by `all ones`? Are you referring to binary and bitwise calculations?

Comment: Yes, all binary ones, mac = ffffffffffff for MAC and 255.255.255.255 for IP.