# Does the IP address assigned to a VLAN have to match the VLAN number?

Tags: vlan

When assigning VLANs in an office building, do the IP addresses I assign to said VLANs HAVE to match the VLAN's number?

For example, say I have a certain department in this office building assigned to VLAN **10**. This department has the network address 10.1.1.0 and the usable address range is 10.1.1.1 – 10.1.1.127. Would this work for this VLAN, or should I have something along the lines of 10.1.**10**.0 for the network address for this VLAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of IP address ranges can be arbitrary, but it is customary to use addresses in the [private address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). With IPv4 these are addresses in the ranges 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255, and 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255.

There's no relationship between a number you use to refer to a certain VLAN and the addresses in that VLAN. Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/353797/345415) about the relationship between IP address ranges (subnets) and VLANs.